# How do I generalize this?

Tags: java, generalization

I have a class `ExampleProperty` that extends the superclass `Property` and in a separate class, `GameObject`, I have an `ArrayList<Property> properties` as well as the following method where `Engine.createEngineObject(new ExampleProperty())` simply adds the `new ExampleProperty()` to a List and returns it back, `propertyId` is an inherited member of `Property`, and where `properties` is the list of `Property`s:

```
public ExampleProperty addExampleProperty()
    {
        ExampleProperty temp = (ExampleProperty)Engine.createEngineObject(new ExampleProperty());
        temp.propertyId = properties.size();
        return temp;
    }
```

I want to generalize this method so I can pass in a `Class<?> propertyClass` and have it return an object the same type as `propertyClass` (and also perform the cast on line 3?). I'm afraid I'm not familiar enough with generalization yet so any help is appreciated :)

EDIT: This is the revised code after the answer was posted. I forgot to mention a bit of info but I worked through it so here's what I have. It's probably awful but it's mine, it works, and I'm proud of it:

```
public <T extends Property> T addProperty(Class<T> propertyClass) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        Property property = propertyClass.newInstance();
        if(propertyClass.getSuperclass() == Engine.class)
        {
            Engine temp = Engine.createEngineObject(propertyClass.newInstance());
            temp.propertyId = properties.size();
            return (T)temp;
        }
        T temp = propertyClass.newInstance();
        temp.propertyId = properties.size();
        return (T)temp;
    }
```

Comment: See my comments on the answer you used to write your update - that was a bad answer to crib notes from, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do the trick:

```java
public <T extends Property> T createEngineObject(Class<T> propertyClass) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    Property property = propertyClass.newInstance();
    // do something...
    return property;
}
```

Although, passing `Property` instance seems like a better idea:

```java
public <T extends Property> T createEngineObject(T property) {
    // do something...
    return property;
}
```

Comment: Dude working on this stuff makes me feel so big brain, but after a bit of tweaking your solution works  100%. Thank you a bunch

Answer (score 0):

Your central issue here is that the things you are doing to `ExampleProperty` aren't captured in a type. Therefore, you can't generalize this verbatim.

Let's list what you 'do' with the currently-hardcoded type (ExampleProperty), so that we know what to capture in types so we can generalize it:

- You invoke its no-args constructor
- You pass the result of that as first arg for a call to `Engine.createEngineObject`.
- You cast the result of `createEngineObject` call to this type.
- You refer to the `propertyId` field of this type.
- You return the type.

Of all those operations, the most problematic one by far is the very first one: **Constructors do not participate in the typing system**. You can't declare 'has a no-args constructor' in a java type. At all. Whatsoever.

There are two solutions to the problem:

1. Leave it stated solely in documentation with zero compile time guarantees, and use a `java.lang.Class` instance as vehicle so that the code knows where to fetch that constructor from. There will be no compile-time checking whatsoever that any type you pass into the genericsed form of this method in fact has a no-args constructor, or that it is non-abstract. If you fail these conditions, the only way you'll ever know is that some exception will occur at runtime.
2. Use factories.

The right answer is of course the second one: Use factories. Capture the concept of 'a thing that can make ExampleProperty instances', because that **can** be conveyed in java's type system. We can use this factory as a vehicle for anything that applies to the entire type, if it comes up:

your generalized code:

```
public interface PropertyFactory<P extends Property> {
    P make();
}
// NB: You can replace the above with `java.util.function.Supplier` instead, but I'd make your own type.

public abstract class Property {
    int propertyId;
}

public <P extends Property> P addProperty(PropertyFactory<P> factory) {
    P temp = Engine.createEngineObject(factory.make());
    temp.propertyId = properties.size();
    return temp;
}

// in Engine.java
public <P extends Property> P createEngineObject(P property) {
    // do stuff here
    return property;
}
```

then to use:

```
private static final PropertyFactory<ExampleProperty> EXAMPLE_MAKER = ExampleProperty::new;

ExampleProperty ep = addProperty(EXAMPLE_MAKER);
```